# redstone problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have several Redstone contraptions on my map, but while trying to build another, I'm having problems with pistons deploying once and getting stuck deployed, even when power is removed. they will not reset or function properly. I don't understand why it won't work anymore.

Comment: You should choose an explanatory title, instead of using words like "problems" to help people reach your question.

Comment: It's happened to me before as well. It has to be a bug with entity movement. All I could do was break the piston block and start over.

Comment: it looks like you've made an inadvertent block update detector.  Keep your redstone lines away from from pistons unless they activate the piston.

Answer (score 2):

You have a BUD piston which can be pretty need sometimes. Just update the piston block after all power is removed then the piston resets itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the timing. Play around with the time that the piston is exposed to a redstone pulse, and use what works, I suppose.